# unknown bitrock_installer.log

Tags: 16.04

I found three instances of /tmp/bitrock_installer.log.  I keep notes of all software I install.  I have no notes for any of these times.

Any idea of what this may be?

```
> ls -l bitrock_installer*
-rw------- 1 tomdean tomdean 161 Oct 14 15:07 bitrock_installer.log
-rw------- 1 tomdean tomdean 161 Nov 22 15:50 bitrock_installer_25200.log
-rw------- 1 tomdean tomdean 161 Nov 10 13:06 bitrock_installer_31539.log
tomdean@P9X79:/tmp$ cat bitrock_installer*.log 
Log started 10/14/2017 at 15:07:39
Preferred installation mode : unattended
Trying to init installer in mode unattended
Mode unattended successfully initialized
Log started 11/22/2017 at 15:50:50
Preferred installation mode : unattended
Trying to init installer in mode unattended
Mode unattended successfully initialized
Log started 11/10/2017 at 13:06:21
Preferred installation mode : unattended
Trying to init installer in mode unattended
Mode unattended successfully initialized
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with this? found [this](http://bitrock.com/products.html) while googling about.

Answer (score 0):

Maple 2016.2 leaves these files each time it is started.